# elasticsearch edge_ngrams analyzer is not found

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following an official video from elasticsearch

and they said to do this:

```
PUT /blablabla/doc/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title" : {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "stemmed" : {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        },
        "autocomplete" : {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "edge_ngrams"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got error that the analyzer edge_ngrams is not exists

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "analyzer [edge_ngrams] not found for field [autocomplete]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "analyzer [edge_ngrams] not found for field [autocomplete]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

why please ?
I am on elasticsearch 2.2

#### Update

calling `GET /blablabla` i get the following

```
{
  "blablabla": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "doc": {
        "properties": {
          "job": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1456267981541",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "5042-5UwR42QY45jMRw8jQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "2010199"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the index settings you get with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/blablabla`?

Comment: Indeed, you must have skipped the part where analyzers were getting installed into the index, since there is no `analysis` section in your index settings.

Comment: @Val in that tutorial they didn't talk about building a custom analyzer, i though the n garm is a built in analyzer.

Comment: Maybe if you provide the link to that tutorial, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of analyzer is `edgeNGram` and not `edge_ngrams`. Checkout this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html)

The default values for min_gram and max_gram are 1 and 2 respectively. In most of the cases, you may need to provide your custom analyzer.

You may like to check how to do this at this [reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

Comment: There is no `edgeNGram` analyzer, but a tokenizer and token filter (i.e. what you linked to). In the question, `edge_ngrams` is the name of a custom analyzer, but it must be missing in the `blablabla` index settings. We'll see when the OP answers to my comment above.

Comment: Agree with you on this